# Azure Synapse Copy pipeline for ingesting complex XML

Tags: xml, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, ingest

I have a copy pipeline set up that connects to an SFTP server (on Azure Synapse).
I have used it to copy csv files and this works fine, but now I have the complex task to pull in a multi-layered xml file and convert it to something usable in the Gen2 data lake (csv or parquet).
I have created my copy pipeline and used various settings but each time, I only get the first record through.
Has anyone experienced this before or have any thoughts on how did to resolve this?

Emily

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not using code 'per se' to create the pipeline.  But the built in Copy pipeline function.  I have now tested it by importing a simpler xml file using copy pipeline and still shen I interrogate the csv file that results, it only has one row, when the xml file I have imported has a number of records.

Comment: I can provide a walk through to recreate the problem:

Comment: Some sample XML which represents your problem would be useful, eg one that has two simple records so we can repro only one being imported.  I recently got [spark-xml working in a Synapse Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72092387/1527504) so that might be worth a look as an alternative.  Also Azure SQL DB is very capable with XML so that might be another option if you have one in your architecture somewhere.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify a collection reference in the mapping section of the pipeline.

Example:

```
<AllEvents>
  <Event>
    <Count>1</Count>
    <Name>John</Name>
  </Event>
  <Event>
    <Count>2</Count>
    <Name>Jane</Name>
  </Event>
</AllEvents>
```

Then specify '$['AllEvents']['Event']' in the Collection reference field, click on 'Import Schemas' once again and redo the mapping. When you run the pipeline again it should import all the rows.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I will work through it again, but I had set up a test copy pipeline using Microsoft's books.xml.  I want to upload a screen shot here but I can't see how.  Anyway, I used the Collection Reference $['catalog']['book'] and then mapped all the fields as you say, but still only one row was ingested.